# How to save an open, editable file in QWebView?

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, qwebview

I have a page open in QWebView which is editable with the `contenteditable` attribute. When a user clicks a save button, I would like to save the content in the file which is already open in the QWebView. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the QWebPage with [QWebView::page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebview.html#page) and the QWebFrame with [QWebPage::mainFrame](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebpage.html#mainFrame). You can then get the content of the page with [QWebFrame::toHtml](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebframe.html#toHtml) and save it to a temporary file

Comment: I apologize for being unclear. I have edited my question.

Comment: `toHtml` will return the page content, but not save the file. And i cannot do a `file.open`, since the file is open in QWebView

Comment: I didn't found anything about unloading the file so you can save on it. Maybe you could make a copy of it, load the copy and save on the real file ?

Comment: That would be an idea, yes. But I am afraid that will give a "bump" while the user might be typing. Currently I am implementing a stack with files that should be updated. When i leave a page or close the application, i will update the file if it's in the stack.

Comment: What do you mean by a "bump" ? A "Lag" ?

Comment: That the page blinks when loading the copy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87292/discussion-between-pascx64-and-attaque).